# Как создать класс, который дает информацию о человеке

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, вложенные-классы

я только начинаю программировать на питоне, прошу помощи. В чем суть: надо создать класс Person, который дает информацию о человеке и имеет:

- вложенный класс Sex -представляет пол человека, имеет следующие значения:
  MALE - мужчина,
  FEMALE - женщина
  атрибуты:
- first_name - имя,

  - last_name - фамилия,
  - age - возраст, не должен быть больше 150 (игнорировать попытки установить возраст больше этого числа),
  - sex - пол, хранит экземпляры вложенного класса Sex

методы:

- конструктор, принимающий на входе значения для всех атрибутов класса
- метод проверки на равенство с другим экземпляром класса Person на основе значений всех атрибутов
- метод для преобразования экземпляра класса Person в строку, строковое представление должно отображать значения всех свойств, например: Петр Петров, мужчина, 18.
  код:

```
    class Person:
     class Sex:
            def __init__(self, MALE, FEMALE):
        def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, age: int, sex: Person.Sex):
        
     
        def age(self, value: int):
            if value <= 150:
                self.age = value
     
        def __eq__(self, other: Person) -> bool:
            return (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.age, self.sex) == 
                   (other.first_name, other.last_name, other.age, other.sex)
     
        def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}, {self.age}, {self.sex}"
```

Класс Person я создал, попытался создать вложенный класс, но похоже сделал неверно, но я не знаю как правильно надо сделать, сделал конструктор, метод для проверки равенства и метод преобразования в строку. Но не работает, как сделать так, чтобы в конструкторе можно было вводить значения,а потом все выводилось в строку? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Вложенный класс должен быть вложен в родительский класс, но не в его методы

Comment: @insolor я изменил, вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Нет. Никакие методы классов не должны пересекаться. Сделайте Sex просто отдельным классом. Потом чтобы он стал вложенным, нужно его вставить класс Sex в Person снаружи от всех методов, и не впихивать методы Person в этот класс.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, первое, что приходит в голову, нужно понять, что при создании объекта Sex() нужно указать такие же и такое же количество аргументов, как в конструкторе. У Вас конструктор принимает на вход два аргумента(MALE, FEMALE), которые потом обрабатываются как переменные, которые хранят какое-то значение. Вы действительно хотите вызывать каждый раз что-то вроде `Пол(мужской=да, женский=нет)`? Не думаю, что Вы хотели этого. Следовательно, можно обойтись простой строкой с полом. Тогда будет вот так:

```
class Person:     
    def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, age: int, sex: str):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age(age)
        self.sex = sex

    def age(self, value: int):
        if value <= 150:
            self.age = value

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.age, self.sex) == (other.first_name, other.last_name, other.age, other.sex)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}, {self.age}, {self.sex}'
    
p = Person('Иван', 'Sidorv', 30, 'male')
```

Тут будет небольшая проблема с тем, что пол может быть и `slkjdhfksjhdf` и `собака`, а не только `male | female`. Но можно обойтись без вложенных классов, которые, кстати, не совсем понятно, зачем нужны...

Можно добавить кастомный для проверки пола. Тогда и безопаснее сеттер, и вложенные классы пригодились. Будет вот так:

```
class Person:
    
    class Sex:
        _suitable_sexes = ('male', 'female')
        def __init__(self, value):
            if value in self._suitable_sexes:
                self._value = value
            else:
                while value not in self._suitable_sexes:
                    value = input(f'Пол не подходит. Введите новый {self._suitable_sexes}: ')
                self._value = value
                
        def get_value(self):
            return self._value

    def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, age: int, sex: str):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age(age)
        self.sex = Person.Sex(sex).get_value()

    def age(self, value: int):
        if value <= 150:
            self.age = value

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.age, self.sex) == (other.first_name, other.last_name, other.age, other.sex)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}, {self.age}, {self.sex}'
    
p = Person('Иван', 'Sidorv', 30, 'mle')
```

К другим мелочам.

1. Всегда, когда у Вас непонятно, что будет в функции, не решили, что написать, пишите `pass`. Иначе питон будет кусаться.
2. Не надо подсказывать питону того, чего он не знает пока. В конструкторе нельзя передать имя своего же класса.

Пока вроде все